# Refresh function not being called properly d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with a scatterplot in d3. Dots on the graph represent a paper. On right click of a dot I have a context menu where there are 2 options: 1) to add that paper to the library (change type to In_library) and 2) Remove from library (remove paper from data completely).

I call the refreshGraph() function after each of these updates which redraws the graph with the updated data. But nothing happens which I assume is because the refreshGraph() is not being called properly? Or for option 1 type library is not being set properly? When refreshGraph is called after option 1 the dot should turn blue and on calling it for option 2 the dot should disappear from display as it has been removed from the alldata which is the data that is being used to draw the circles. Here is the relevant code:

```
allData = [];

var menu = [{
title: 'Add to Library',
action: function addToLibrary(elem, d, i) {

    d3.json("connection6.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

        for(i=0;i<allData.length;i++){ 
            if (d.type === "In_library")
            {
            alert("The paper: " + d.TITLE + " is already in your Library!"); 
                    return; 
            }
            }

            d.type = "In_library"; // is this the correct way to change the type if the input has a different type??
            refreshGraph();

        })
        refreshGraph();
    }

}, 
{
title: 'Remove from Library',
action: function removeFromLibrary (elem, d, i) {

        d3.json("connection9.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

            //loop through allData and if selected ID has type In_library, remove from allData
            for(i=0;i<allData.length;i++){
                if (d.type == "In_library"){
                    allData.splice(i--,1);      
            }
            }
            refreshGraph();
            })  
    }

}
]

function refreshGraph() { 

// draw dots
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(allData)

    circles.transition()
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})

    circles.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(YearFn(d))})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(Num_citationsFn(d))})
        .style("fill",function(d){
                    var colour = "black"
                    switch(d.type){

                    case "In_library":
                        colour = "blue";
                    break;
                    case "cited by":
                        colour = "red";
                    break;
                    case "cites":
                        colour = "green";
                    break;
                    case "selected":
                        colour = "magenta";
                    break;
                    default:
                        colour = "black";
                    }
                    return colour;
                    }) 

        .on("mouseover", mouseHandler)
        .on("mouseout", mouseoutHandler)
        .on("click", clickHandler)
        .on("contextmenu", rightClickHandler);


svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis); 
svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

//don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
x.domain([d3.min(allData, YearFn)-1, d3.max(allData, YearFn)+1]);
y.domain([d3.min(allData, Num_citationsFn)-1, d3.max(allData, Num_citationsFn)+1]);

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated I am new to d3 so thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget to update `allData` in your function `addTolibrary`?

Comment: @Quarter2Twelve yes good point do you mean push(d) into allData? If so that shouldnt be the case as if a dot is displayed and can be clicked it mean it is already in allData.. so if I push that paper into allData it draws another instance of that paper ontop of it instead of which I would like the type to be recognised as In_library and change the colour of the existing dot. I did try that and saw a blue dot but realised it  was merely covering another dot.

Comment: When you call refreshGraph, what are you doing with the circles that are already plotted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-plot all the data each time a single point changes. Just update that one point.

```
function rightClickHandler() {

   // if option 1
   d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");

   // if option 2
   d3.select(this).remove();

}
```

Your problem likely arises because when you call refreshGraph a second time (or third) your aren't clearly the circles that are already plotted. Your refreshGraph function isn't updating the points already plotted it's recreating them each time, and if you aren't clearing the points that are already there, you won't see the new points (or the absence of them, or the change in color), because they are hidden behind your old points.

**EDIT:**

If you want to re-add the data each time, you first have to clear the existing data. At the start of your refreshGraph function, add this line:

```
if(!d3.selectAll("circle").empty()) d3.selectAll("circle").remove();
```

i.e. if there are circle elements, remove them. This assumes you are only creating circle elements within the refreshGraph function. If you create them elsewhere, the you should probably use the .dot selector instead.

Comment: ah ok I think I see where your coming from. Adding data isnt an issue so the issue lies when I need to change a dot to a different type as I first need to remove it then redraw it (I want refreshgraph to redraw this in the color that it recognises the type as - therefore I dont really want to use your setAttribute(this) if I can avoid it). And the same with removing from library I may have removed it from the data but I havent removed it from the display. Sorry I am talking through my thoughts here so would you be able to give me pointers on how I can remove the original and redraw??

Comment: excellent! really appreciate that, just to ask you one more question.. when I select the remove from library option and call refresh graph everything is removed from display when I need only the selected circle to be removed... how would I go about doing this within the removeFromLibrary function? Is my loop correct or even necessary? You first edit `d3.select(this).remove();` makes sense to me but when I place it in the removeFromLibrary function it doesnt work.. I hope you can help me I really appreciate the feedback @James

Comment: It's tough to answer your question without seeing the complete code. "this" refers to the dot you clicked so if you move into another function you won't be able to access it. You can pass it to your "function rightClickHandler(dot)" like this "rightClickHandler(this)". Within that function, you can then pass it to your removeFromLibrary function like this "removeFromLibrary(dot)" and remove it as d3.select(dot).remove().

Comment: I cant seem to get your answer working but I understand its difficult to give advice on such little code but with all my connections and links to the db I dont really know how to reproduce an example. Do you think it would be feasible if say in my removeFromLibrary function and within the connection I set the type of the selected dot to "remove". I was thinking then I could have a check in my refreshGraph function that `if d.type = "remove" ` delete it from allData which should delete it from display? I tried `allData.splice(d)` but doesnt seem to do anything..  Sorry for bugging you :( @James

Comment: Of course that should work. When you call refreshData just make sure you clear any dots that have been drawn already as I suggest above. Then draw your data again, except if a datum has type "remove". Just to be clear, this will clear and redraw all your data again. If you update allData, that won't automatically update any drawn points as your data array is not dynamically linked to the points, it's just used for drawing them initially.

Comment: Ok perfect, so does this mean I should have the drawing of the circles in a loop? Or can I just define it at the start of the function as a function?  should this line work in refreshGraph `function removeDot (d){ if d.type === "remove" {allData.splice(d)}` (this will be my last q for you apologies) @James

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're after. Do you want to remove the point from your array all-together or do you just want to remove the displayed dot? If you want to remove it from the array, that would probably be easiest to do in your removeFromLibrary function - splice it from the array, then in refreshGraph, remove all circles and redraw with your new data array. Alternatively, and assuming your array is an array of objects, you could mark the datum you want to remove with remove: true, then when you go to fill the dot: ".style("fill",function(d){ if(!d.remove) ...